# Norm of $H=\{u\in L^2(Ω): \operatorname{div}u=0,\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0\}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, divergence-operator

In the study of **Navier Stokes Equations**,

Let us consider the set:

$V: =${$ϕ∈C_c^{\infty}(Ω)$, div$ϕ =0$}.

$C_c^{\infty}(Ω)$:= space of $C^{\infty}(Ω)$ with compact support, where $Ω \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is open.

We can then define the following fundamental space:

$H$: as the closure of $V$ in $L^2(Ω)$.

As in the reference, this space is of course **Hilbert space** equipped with the scalar product induced by that of $L^2(Ω)$.

Furthermore, and after some proofs,

$H=${$u∈L^2(Ω)$, div$u$ =0,$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}:=\nabla u.n=0$}, where $n$ is an outward unit vector.

**My Question is**,

How to express $||u||_H$
where $u \in H$?

I am little lost because (as told in reference), $\exists$ a continuous embedding from $H$ to $L^2(Ω)$, so one can say

$||u||_{L^2(Ω)} \le$ cst.$||u||_H$

and if you answered me that $||u||_H:=||u||_{L^2(Ω)}$, $\forall u \in H$, I would be somehow confused, since then what is the benefit of telling that $H$ is continuously embedded in $L^2(Ω)$

Some help please!!

Comment: I think it is $\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$.  It has to be.  It isn't false that $H$ is continuously embedded in $L^2(\Omega)$.  There is nothing special about $L^2(\Omega)$ - think of the closure of any subspace of any Banach space.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Sorry but what do you mean:" think of the closure of any subspace of any Banach space"?

Comment: If $V$ is a subspace of a Banach space $X$, then the closure of $V$ in $X$ has the same norm as $X$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Sounds true, but how can we then say, as I mentioned above, that:$||u||_{L^2(Ω)} \le$ cst.$||u||_H$? How can it remain true?

Comment: It is true with constant equal to 1.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Okay thanks so much